# Unable to create pagination for Category.php

Tags: categories, pagination

I'm trying to make a pagination for my category.php. My posts are custom post type.
I get a 404 not found error when I'm trying to get to the second page. I realised that this is happening only for category.php and not another page/template.

The code is:

```
<?php                        
                $paged = get_query_var('paged');

                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'cat' => $cat,
                'posts_per_page' => 20,
                'paged' => $paged
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :              
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <div class="product">
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                            </div> 
                            <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                        </div>    
                    </a>                   
                <?php 
                endwhile;?> 
                <div class="pagination-container">
                    <div class="pagination">
                        <?php 
                        echo paginate_links(array(
                            'total' => $query->max_num_pages
                        ));?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check up the  [wordpress templating hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png) The graphics reads from left to right.
You have custom post type **products** so you can override this file and your code should be in category-products.php, since you are limiting your WP queury for **products posts**. Category.php is similar but without this limitation.

```
   // Your category-products.php loop should be like this
   <!-- Prepare query -->
   $your_query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'products',
     'posts_per_page' => 20,
   ));

   if ( $your_query ->have_posts() ) :

   while ( $your_query ->have_posts() ) : $your_query ->the_post();?>
   <!-- Show a card -->
   <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
   <div class="product">
   <div class="image-container">
   <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
   </div> 
   <p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
   </div>    
   </a>   

   <!-- loop-end -->
   <?php endwhile;  ?>

   <!-- pagination -->
   <div class="col-md-8 post_paginations" style="text-align:center;">
   <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
   'mid_size'  => 2,
   'screen_reader_text' => __( ' ', 'theme_name' ),
   'prev_text' => __( 'Previous', 'theme_name' ),
   'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'theme_name' ),
   ) ); ?>
   </div>

   <!-- Else -->
   <?php else : ?>
   <h1><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></h1>
   <?php endif; ?>
```